# Using for loop to remove a whole category at a time?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have a fairly alrge dataset and I am running a for loop to remove one line per transect and calculate the frequency of the category. I am now trying to make it so that instead of one line per transect it removes a whole transect every iteration. Is it possible to do this?

Here is a sample dataset with the same columns I have

```
Transect<- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
Category<- c("S","S","S","C","T","S","SP","T", "C", "T","S","SP","T","S","C")
dat<- data.frame(Transect,Category)
```

So the current code below removes one line per transect. How could I do it so that it randomly deletes a whole transect category (i.e. in the first iteration all of transect 3 is removed and on the second all of 1 is removed)

```
for (q in 1:2) {
  
  
  for ( i in 0:5){
    #if (i>0)
    
    df<- dat2 %>%
      group_by(Transect) %>%
      sample_n(n() - i, replace = TRUE) %>%
      ungroup()
    
    
    c<-df %>%                               
      group_by(Category) %>%
      summarise(n = n(), replace=TRUE) %>%
      mutate(freq = n / sum(n), 
             total=55-i) 
    if (i==0){
      tot_1=c
    } else {
      tot_1=bind_rows(tot_1,c)
    }
  }
  tot_1$rep = q 
  if (q==1){
    dftot = tot_1
  } else {
    dftot=bind_rows(dftot, tot_1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a bunch of random simulations and store the results or systematically tabulate the distribution of `Category` values while removing on `Transect` group at a time?

Comment: Tabulate the distribution of category values while removing one transect group at a time. My actual dataset has 100 transects and 55 points (rows) per transect. So I am trying to see how the removal of one whole transect at a time changes the accuracy of the frequency calculation. (using all 100 transects would be the most accurate while when only down to 1 transect its less reflective of the actual frequency). Is it as simple as just making sure i=5?

Comment: But you might have a few highly influential transects so you need to test them each right?

Comment: In theory yes but in this case I want to remove them randomly. For context, in real life scientists randomly place transects and points and calculate what the % cover of plants is. So like a forest may be 20% trees, 60%shrub and 20% grass. I want to see how many random transects actually need to be placed before deviating too much from whats actually there.

Comment: OK, so iteratively remove 1 random, then 2 random and keep going and each time show the distribution. Then assess how much it changed the distribution. Correct?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Is that possible in a for loop?

Comment: Does this accomplish the sampling/removal you are trying to do? `sapply(split(rownames(dat), dat$Transect), sample, size=1); dat2 <- dat[! rownames(dat) %in% idx, ]`. If so, it should not be difficult to modify to take progressively more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your goals is to iteratively assess increasingly small subsamples of your data to assess loss of representation of the whole. This code will try dropping a random 1 then 2 then 3... and report the distribution of categories. The last few lines normalize count to fraction of total for easy comparison between iterations.

Note I used `set.seed()` because it will return a different result each time due to random sampling.

To break down this answer a bit:

1. It's important that `Category` is a `factor` so that `table()` won't drop any `Category` values that have no count in a particular iteration. It would run to a point but then the rowbinding operation within `map_dfr()` would fail.
2. First I just enumerate the numbers of `Transect` to leave out (should be 0:4 in this example) using `0:length(unique(d$Transect))`. I included 0 so that we can see what it looks like with the full dataset.
3. I used `set_names()` so that it becomes a named vector. This allows us to use `.id` inside `map_dfr()` so that we get an extra column which stores the value of the leaveout.
4. `purrr::map_dfr()` will iteratively apply a function over some list. In this case I piped in the list of leaveout values (which we just named) and the function we apply is given as an rlang-style [lambda](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) function which begins with `~` and operates on the argument `.x`.
5. Working from the inside of the `filter` operation, this function first randomly samples a number of values of `Transect` to exclude given by `.x` and then removes data with said value of `Transect`. Here we use `%in%` and negate the whole result with `!` at the beginning.
6. Then we just use `dplyr::pull()` to take the `Category` column as a `vector` and run `table()` on it to tabulate the occurrence of each value.
7. The rest just calculates the total count for each iteration and then divides the values by that to get a fraction.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
  Transect = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)),
  Category = factor(c("S","S","S","C","T","S","SP","T", "C", "T","S","SP","T","S","C"))
)

set.seed(1)
0:length(unique(d$Transect)) %>% set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr( ~ d %>% 
             filter(!Transect %in% sample(unique(d$Transect), size = .x)) %>% 
             pull(Category) %>% 
             table(),
           .id = "leaveout_transects") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total_count = sum(c_across(-1)), .after = 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(1:2), ~.x/total_count))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   leaveout_transects total_count C       S       SP        T        
#>   <chr>                    <int> <table> <table> <table>   <table>  
#> 1 0                           15 0.2     0.4     0.1333333 0.2666667
#> 2 1                           10 0.2     0.3     0.2000000 0.3000000
#> 3 2                            5 0.2     0.2     0.2000000 0.4000000
#> 4 3                            0 NaN     NaN           NaN       NaN
```

It would probably be more rigorous to simulate each leaveout condition multiple times and look at the distribution of performance you get at each value to assess what's likely to happen in the future with a given subsample.

Base `r` has the built in function `replicate` which is great for this purpose. Here I'm just using the code above with `replicate` and then reformatting the data a bit to graph it.

```r
# use replicate to make many simulations
n_reps <- 20
replicate(
  n_reps,
  0:length(unique(d$Transect)) %>% set_names() %>%
    map_dfr(
      ~ d %>%
        filter(!Transect %in% sample(unique(d$Transect), size = .x)) %>%
        pull(Category) %>%
        table(),
      .id = "leaveout_transects"
    ) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(total_count = sum(c_across(-1)), .after = 1) %>%
    mutate(across(-c(1:2), ~ .x / total_count)) %>%
    select(3:6) %>%
    t() %>%
    cor() %>%
    .[, 1]) %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>%
  mutate("leavout_transects" = factor(0:length(unique(d$Transect)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-leavout_transects, values_to = "correlation") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(leavout_transects, correlation)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to run it on my end now with my actual dataset but I keep getting "Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Argument 134 must have names." I checked my dataset and have no missing values or anything of that sort. My transect category is shown as a charactr and not numerical value. Is this why?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. But you need to convert `Category` to a `factor`, otherwise `table()` will drop any values with no count and you won't have the same columns to enable rowbinding.

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks so much. Now to dissect your code to actually understand it but thanks!!

Comment: I can add some explanation to break it down a bit. Also have a way to repeat it so you can simulate many leaveouts at each value quickly if you like.

Comment: Both would be excellent if you dont mind!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to keep bothering you but is there a way to then convert the outputs into a typical dataframe?

Comment: Sure. You can stop the code just before `ggplot()` to get all the replicates in 'long' format or before `pivot_longer()` to get it in 'wide' format.